# Vue.js Computed Property Filtering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue.js computed property as follows.

```
odds() {
    let race = this.data.events.runners.filter(item => item.course === this.course && item.time === this.time)
    let runner = race[0].data.filter(item => item.name === this.runner)
    return runner[0].odds
}
```

Although it returns the expected value I think it looks dirty. Can any one suggest best way to write this code.

Sample JSON is as follows.

```
{
    "courses": [{
        "type": "horses",
        "course": "Exeter"
    }],
    "runners": [{
        "course": "Exeter",
        "time": "14:10",
        "data": [{
            "number": "1",
            "name": "White Lilac",
            "odds": "6\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "2",
            "name": "Sauvignon",
            "odds": "5\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "3",
            "name": "Foxy Lass",
            "odds": "33\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "4",
            "name": "Hot Ryan",
            "odds": "8\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "5",
            "name": "Arqalina",
            "odds": "11\/8"
        }, {
            "number": "6",
            "name": "Presenting Lucina",
            "odds": "14\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "7",
            "name": "Persistantprincess",
            "odds": "12\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "8",
            "name": "Windy Bottom",
            "odds": "20\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "9",
            "name": "Shotgun Sally",
            "odds": "33\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "10",
            "name": "Rule The Ocean",
            "odds": "9\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "11",
            "name": "Avithos",
            "odds": "12\/1"
        }, {
            "number": "12",
            "name": "Monet Moor",
            "odds": "16\/1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I would like to know if there is a much better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's invalid sample JSON...

Comment: @tony19 i updated my question. please check it now.

Comment: Are you expecting only client side suggestions? do you have the ability to change the JSON structure from backend?

Comment: @ShyamBabu yes i only expect 1 client side suggestion. and yes i have full ability to make any change

Comment: what i want is when a runner is selected from a select dropdown i need to assign its odds value to another text box.

Comment: I think this question would be better received on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code is nice enough. but one change is your course and time make it unique fields so there will only be one index always so its better to exit early. (you can add false check for not found yourself).

```
var requiredCourse = (courseDetails)=>courseDetails.course === this.selectedCourse && courseDetails.time === this.selectedTime;
var requiredhorse = (horse)=> horse.name === this.runner;

var courseIndex = data.findIndex(requiredCourse);
var horseOdds = data[courseIndex].data.findIndex(requiredhorse);
console.log(data[courseIndex].data[horseOdds])
```

But if you have the ability to change the JSON structure. then just directly make the course and time as keys so you can directly access without need for filter or findIndex. hope this make is it little bit cleaner for your liking.